# GitHub API: Identify the branches that contain a given commit

Tags: github

Given the SHA of a specific commit in my repo, I want to identify the branches which contain the commit, **using the GitHub API**.

I'm aware I can do this locally using `git` directly in a variety of ways, including

```
git branch --contains <commit>
```

but this is for an integrated page that's pulling data from several platforms, so I really need to be using the API.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517405/get-git-commits-by-branch-name-id-with-git-api) had an accepted answer saying this wasn't possible back in 2013, but I'm hoping something along these lines has been added to the API since.

Is anyone aware of a way to get this information short of querying for a list of ALL commits in the branches of interest and iterating through them to compare?

Comment: Seems what is suggested here works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32630712/4096840

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the [Repository Commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit), [Git Commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#get-a-commit) nor [Git References](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/) endpoints provide that data, so I think the API just doesn't do it.

But the website *shows* that data, so if you desperately need it you could try scraping the commit's page (`https://github.com/:user/:repo/commit/:sha`) and getting the `commit-branches` div.

Finally, Github's Support is great, so you should ask them - worst-case scenario is they tell you it's not implemented, but maybe they put it on the TO-DO list.

Comment: This doesn't work. When I run `git branch --contains SHA`, I see that my commit is in my `staging` branch and also in `master` when staging was later merged in there. GitHub only shows that it is in `staging`, the branch it was originally merged into.

Answer (score 8):

Could not find s.th. neither, ended up using unofficial API (I guess):

https://github.com/:user/:repo/branch_commits/:commit

You still need to scrape the response, but it's much shorter and faster. If the response just contains whitespace, there is no branch for that commit.

Comment: i'm also trying to use it so curious, was html response changed for you since these years or it was stable enough?

Comment: I honestly don't remember in which project I used this and therefore can not tell if it works. Sorry.