# List branches that specific commit part of through GitHub API

Tags: git, github, github-api

I have a sha1 of a git commit on GitHub and i need to understand to what branch that commit belongs through GitHub API.

For example we have this repo - https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/commits/master and example commit that isn't HEAD - [GitHub API](https://api.github.com/repos/mono/gtk-sharp/git/commits/3d0d5a9670c897d5353a99c67d519e9fc6dbcb8e) and [UI](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/commit/3d0d5a9670c897d5353a99c67d519e9fc6dbcb8e)

GitHub has a nice preview APIs there - https://developer.github.com/changes/2019-04-11-pulls-branches-for-commit/ and [here](https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#list-branches-for-head-commit) but they are working only for commit that is a HEAD so i can't use it.

GitHub also has some kind of internal API for that as in UI that information is displayed here on screenshot below. I can get that data from https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/branch_commits/3d0d5a9670c897d5353a99c67d519e9fc6dbcb8e but it's not official API and i can't normally use it with GitHub Token for private repositories.

[image]

It's also doable through `git branch -r --contains <commmit>` but it requires to have that git repository locally and i can't use that approach.

I couldn't find anything for that in neither GitHub [REST](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/) or [GraphQL](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) APIs so any ideas would be appreciated. I probably can get list of commits of all branches and then traverse them to find it but it would be too slow. Also there was older question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992441/github-api-identify-the-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit) but maybe something changed in last 5 years.

Thanks.

Comment: Yet another old answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23970412/7976758

Comment: This is not a part of the API because in general, it can be very slow.

Comment: @bk2204 it makes sense why it could be very slow, but i was hoping since the same data is displayed on GitHub UI page for each commit, it can be exposed through API as well. but yeah, i understand the reasons