# Github api to get all the commits done to given repository branch

Tags: git, github, github-api, github-api-v3

I am trying to get all the commits given to `develop` branch of repository `test` using github api but I am always getting first page no matter how i pass the query params. Not sure what's wrong in the request I am sending.

```sh
curl -u username:$token -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/ORGANIZATION_NAME/test/commits/develop
```

I am always getting the first page. I have tried using the query params given [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#list-commits)

Comment: [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/) might be useful

Comment: Seems what suggested here works:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32630712/4096840

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are accessing the wrong endpoint. The one you are sending to is [this one](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#get-a-commit), where you are only getting one commit (in your case the latest `develop` commit).

You need to implement some pagination logic to your app and access this endpoint: `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits`.

So for instance, to get the commits of your development branch, you would send such a request:

```
curl -H "Authorization: XYZ" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/ACCNAME/REPO/commits\?sha\=develop
```

(if you are using the [octokit](https://github.com/octokit/core.js), it would be prettier, but this is just an example :))

Now, in order for you to paginate, you would need to also query for the `per_page` and `page` parameters and check if you've hit the limit or not.

Basically, with the following query:

```
curl -H "Authorization: XYZ" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/ACCNAME/REPO/commits\?sha\=develop\&per_page\=X\&page\=Y
```

Where `X` and `Y` are parameters you pass to the `curl` request. Once you get a response, you check if the length of the array (since you'll get an array of commits) is equal to `X`. If it is, do another request, but this time, increment `Y+1`, that way you'll get the next page. Loop through this process until the response you get is **less** than the required `X`, since that way you will know you would have gotten the last commits from your repo.

---

An example in node (disclaimer, not properly written code)

```js
let allCommits = [];

let call = function(n, y) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getCommits(function(statusCode, result) {
            allCommits.push(result);
            if (result.length === y) {
               call(n + 1, y);
            }
        }, n, y);
    });
};
```

If `getCommits` is your function to get a range of commits from a branch, with a `path` defined as `path: '/repos/ACC_NAME/REPO/commits?sha=develop&page=' + n + '&per_page=' + y`, then in the end you would have all the pages of commits in the `allCommits` array. You'll just have to flatten it out in the end, but someone with better js skill can provide a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: thanks a lot :) ... it works like a charm. Maybe i should have given more focus on the endpoint from the begining.